# Calculate number of days until nth day of month

Tags: excel

I can use `=DATE(2019,1,20)-TODAY()` to calculate the number of days until the 20th of January. How can I calculate the number of days until the 20th day of any month (with *0* being the result on the 20th day)?

Comment: By any month do you mean the current month?

Comment: The calendar month from the 20th day.

Comment: Can you provide a sample, just to make sure I follow? For example, 20 days from the 23rd of December is the 12th of January, which is 8 days away from the January 20th - is this what you mean?

Comment: Today (23 December) is 28 days until the 20th day of the calendar month beginning the 20th of December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can be simplified but I'd break it down into the following logic:

- If the day - i.e. the 23rd - is less than or equal to 20, then take the difference between the two.
- Otherwise, calculate the 20th day of the next month, and take the difference.

Something like this:

```
=IF(DAY(A2)<=20,20-DAY(A2),DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(A2,1)),MONTH(EOMONTH(A2,1)),20)-A2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to define "any month".  If you're looking for the current month, you can do:

```
=DATE(year(today()),month(today()),20)-TODAY()
```

Which will calculate to the current month.  Essentially, you're just replacing the "1" in your original formula.  That depends on how you want to determine the month.

If you're looking to track the number of days until the next 20th of a month, then you'll need to track the year and month in cells and increment them when the formula is < 0 (noting that the increment on the year is dependent on if the month is 12. And you'll need logic to move month to 1 and not 13.